# Проблема в редактировании названия и описания шаблона в 1с-битрикс

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс

Всем привет, создал новый шаблон в 1с-битриксе. В папке с шаблоном есть 3 файла, header.php, footer.php, desription.php. В description php лежит код:`

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>



$arTemplate = [
    'NAME' => 'named',
    'DESCRIPTION' => 'descd',
];
```

Имя и описание не меняются, а код лежит в самой шапке сайта[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли обернуть свой код в `<?` и `?>`

```
<?

$arTemplate = [
    'NAME' => 'named',
    'DESCRIPTION' => 'descd',
];

?>
```

А строку ниже можно вообще убрать

```
<? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>
```

Comment: ойййй, спасибо, а я думаю, почему мне так стыдно